# Flare is not animated

Tags: flutter, dart

I created flare on Rive. But it's not animated. Only showing image.

```
class CustomIntro extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return

      Column(
      children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
          child: FlareActor(
            'assets/introduction.flr',
              alignment:Alignment.center,
              fit:BoxFit.contain,
              animation:"introduction",
          )
      )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see **ANIMATIONS** sidebar on the rive.app. Add this name to the flutter code.

```
   FlareActor(
              "assets/Introduction.flr",
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              animation: "go",
            )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem here that is the wrong animation name (each Flare file has some animation names...)

**Example below**: favorite.flr have 2 animation names (Favorite + Unfavorite)

```
class CustomIntro extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            child: FlareActor(
          'res/favorite.flr',
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          animation: "Favorite", // or Unfavorite
        ))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Please correct it and try again.